# detect Iframe on loadcomplete event?

Tags: javascript, iframe, httprequest

I have an aspx page containing an iFrame in it. The iFrame loads a URL online and that URL online will then automatically be redirect to another page online too. What I'm trying to achieve is to make sure that the iFrame loaded all the content within it before redirect the user to another page on my site using Response.Redirect() from code behind.

What i'm looking for is something like this:

```
iframe1.onloadcomplete = function(){
  //redirect here
};
```

Comment: Does the iFrame content come from the same server as the page it is on? (same origin). Iframes do have onload attributes too so perhaps `<iframe onload="yourfunction()` would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
iframe1.onload = function(){
  //redirect here
};
```